# Initialization of number of free pages in each order in a memory zone

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, kernel

I am going through the memory initialization code in linux kernel, and I can see the number of free
pages for each order and migration type for the each memory zone in a memory node is set to 0.

```
static void __meminit zone_init_free_lists(struct zone *zone)
{
int order, t;
for_each_migratetype_order(order, t) {
INIT_LIST_HEAD(&zone->free_area[order].free_list[t]);
zone->free_area[order].nr_free = 0;
}
}
```

I am not able to figure out how the list is set to the proper state, as in which order has how many default
pages to to start with, or we start with all entries in the highest order.

In the book, I read the following:

> The number of free pages (nr_free) is still currently defined as 0, and this obviously does not reflect
>   the true situation. The correct value is not set until the bootmem allocator is disabled and normal buddy
>   allocation comes into effect.

Can someone point to the actual location where this part is set to the default starting value?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a call `mem_init()`, which marks the free areas in the `mem_map` and tells us how much memory is free. This is done after various parts of the system have claimed their memory after the kernel image.

which further calls `free_unused_memmap()` and `free_all_bootmem()` api's to free the memory (in pages) and will adds the free memory chunks(in pages) into different orders `free_lists`.

You can print the zones(Normal, Highmem etc) related information using `show_free_areas()`.

The result of the `show_free_areas()` before/after freeing all bootup and other mem_map related memory.

**Before:**

Normal free:**0kB ... present:778240kB managed:772160kB ... etc**

HighMem free:**0kB ... present:270336kB managed:270336kB ... etc**

Normal: 0*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = **0kB**

HighMem: 0*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = **0kB**

**After:**

Normal free:**542868kB ... present:778240kB managed:542868kB ... etc**

HighMem free:**270336kB ... present:270336kB managed:270336kB ... etc**

Normal: 5*4kB (M) 2*8kB (M) 3*16kB (M) 4*32kB (M) 3*64kB (M) 4*128kB (M) 3*256kB (M) 7*512kB (M) 7*1024kB (M) 9*2048kB (M) 125*4096kB (M) = **542868kB**

HighMem: 0*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 66*4096kB (M) = **270336kB**